# return value other that $? from ssh session

Tags: shell, ssh

How do I return a value other than $? from a ssh session

for example:

```
x=5
echo "$x"
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@hostname "x=10"
echo "$x"
```

This will print

```
5
5
```

But I need new value

```
5
10
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try this:

```
x=5 
echo "$x"
x=$(ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@hostname 'x=10; echo $x')
echo "$x"
```

What happens here is you capture the output of the command executed remotely, and assign that output to your local variable `x`. Notice, that I used single quotes, not double quotes, to quote the remote command: `'x=10; echo $x'`. `$x` in a string in double quotes would get replaced by value of local `x` before being sent to the remote host, so you would get 5 printed by the remote command and assigned to your local `x`.

Comment: Thanks. This was actually easy. I don't know why I didn't think of this.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it as follows:

```
x=5
echo "$x"
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@hostname 'x=10; exit $x'
echo "$?"
```

**Explanation:**

- `'x=10; exit $x'` - These are the instructions you are passing via `ssh` to be run remotely on `root@hostname`. Therefore, you want to enclose them in single quotes instead of double quotes to prevent auto-expansion of `$x` in your local shell.
- Note a subtle distinction here: the variable `x` in your local shell is **not** the same `x` in the remote shell spawned via your `ssh` session.
- `$?` is a special shell variable that stores the exit status of your most recently run command in your local shell. Since we told the `ssh` session to exit with `10`, that's what it prints with `echo "$?"`

Comment: Dude, this works only with numbers but not with text. Thanks for your help, but I will be accepting piokuc's answer as it works with numbers and text. The Error reported is "numeric argument required".

Comment: It's no problem; your question title specified `$?` so I assumed you were interested in return value of `ssh` (return values are traditionally integers between `0-255` for unix commands)